# QField unable to fetch new points from WFS

Tags: qgis, qfield

I created a simple QGIS project with a single editable WFS layer that uses basic auth. This layer is published using Geoserver from a PostGIS DB. I packaged the QGIS project for QField with the plugin and loaded it onto my device. I am able to save a single new point without error, but with all subsequent points I get this error:

> Layer culverts has been commited [sic] but newly created feature -9
> could not be fetched

I am able to refresh the layer to see the new points (and the changes are verified in QGIS), but since the user does not see the point added, it is common to accidentally add multiple points in the same location.

Any idea what is causing this error? The expected behaviour would be for all new points  to appear on the map without error.